# Fail to create 2 table in Android Studio using SQLite

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio

I have created 2 table, but the others is still not found. The table won't created but i have create in database helper using execSQL

```
2019-12-28 23:42:18.971 30262-30262/com.example.ppdb E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: peserta
2019-12-28 23:42:18.972 30262-30262/com.example.ppdb E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting tgl_lahir= agama= jk= tmp_lahir= alamat= nama=Anto
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: peserta (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO peserta(tgl_lahir,agama,jk,tmp_lahir,alamat,nama) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

This is my DatabaseHelper using TABLE_PESERTA = 'peserta'

```
public class DatabasePesertaHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Database {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = DatabaseContents.DATABASE.toString();


public DatabasePesertaHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE peserta" + "("
            + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + "nama TEXT(100),"
            + "jenis_kelamin TEXT(1),"
            + "tempat_lahir TEXT(20),"
            + "tgl_lahir TEXT(12),"
            + "alamat TEXT(30),"
            + "agama TEXT(30),"
            + "id_ortu INTEGER,"
            + "FOREIGN KEY (id_ortu) REFERENCES " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_USERS + "(_id)"
            + ");");
    Log.d("CREATE DATABASE", "Create " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_PESERTA  +" Successfully.");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_PESERTA);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Anyone can help me pls?
Thank you!

Comment: If you added the 2nd table later after you created the 1st then uninstall the app from the device and rerun to recreate the database.

Comment: Where is the other table created? They should be in the same sqlite helper.

Answer (score 0):

## Explanation

It would appear that you are trying to use multiple Database Helpers, one per table for the same database. **Only one Helper**, the first, encountered for the lifetime of the database, will call the **onCreate** method and therefore the likely issue that you are encountering.

The typical fix would be to use a single Database Helper (it is not a table helper).

Assume that you have a database helper for the **Users** table that is :-

```
public class DatabaseUserHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = DatabaseContents.DATABASE.toString();

    public DatabaseUserHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("CREATEUSER","Creating User Table");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_USERS +
                "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                " username text" +
                ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

and you have the DatabasePesertaHelper as you have included in the question, then using :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseUserHelper userHelper = new DatabaseUserHelper(this);
        logTables(userHelper.getWritableDatabase());
        DatabasePesertaHelper pesertaHelper = new DatabasePesertaHelper(this);
        logTables(pesertaHelper.getWritableDatabase());

    }

    private void logTables(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Cursor c = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
        c.close();
    }
}
```

And the App is run, from new, then the log contains :-

```
12-29 09:34:28.582 2511-2511/? D/CREATEUSER: Creating User Table


12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@1351978
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out: 0 {
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    rootpage=3
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out: }
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out: 1 {
12-29 09:34:28.587 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    name=users
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=users
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    rootpage=4
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE users(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text)
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out: }
12-29 09:34:28.588 2511-2511/? I/System.out: <<<<<


12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@fdb49b7
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: 0 {
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    rootpage=3
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: }
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: 1 {
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    name=users
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    tbl_name=users
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    rootpage=4
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE users(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text)
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: }
12-29 09:34:28.590 2511-2511/? I/System.out: <<<<<
```

i.e. The **User** table has been created, although the DatabasePesertaHelper has not issues, the Peserta table is not created (if order of instantiating the usersHelper and pesertaHelper were swapped and pesertaHelper was the first then only the Peserta table would be created and then ONLY if the database did not exist).

## Suggested Fix

The typical fix would be to combine both tables into the one helper and to then uninstall the App and to rerun.

- Note that this will delete all existing data, this typically acceptable when developing an App.

As such the DatabaseUserHelper as shown above could become :-

```
public class DatabaseUserHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = DatabaseContents.DATABASE.toString();

    public DatabaseUserHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("CREATEUSER","Creating User Table");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_USERS +
                "(" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                " username text" +
                ")");

        Log.d("CREATEPESERTA","Creating Perserta Table");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE peserta" + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "nama TEXT(100),"
                + "jenis_kelamin TEXT(1),"
                + "tempat_lahir TEXT(20),"
                + "tgl_lahir TEXT(12),"
                + "alamat TEXT(30),"
                + "agama TEXT(30),"
                + "id_ortu INTEGER,"
                + "FOREIGN KEY (id_ortu) REFERENCES " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_USERS + "(_id)"
                + ");");
        Log.d("CREATE DATABASE", "Create " + DatabaseContents.TABLE_PESERTA + " Successfully.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

After deleteting the App's Data (or uninstalling the App) and rerunning the activity code above results in :-

```
12-29 10:01:37.265 D/CREATEUSER: Creating User Table
12-29 10:01:37.265 D/CREATEPESERTA: Creating Perserta Table
12-29 10:01:37.265 D/CREATE DATABASE: Create peserta Successfully.
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@1351978
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: 0 {
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: 1 {
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    name=users
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    tbl_name=users
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE users(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text)
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: 2 {
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    name=peserta
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    tbl_name=peserta
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE peserta(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nama TEXT(100),jenis_kelamin TEXT(1),tempat_lahir TEXT(20),tgl_lahir TEXT(12),alamat TEXT(30),agama TEXT(30),id_ortu INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY (id_ortu) REFERENCES users(_id))
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.270 I/System.out: <<<<<
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@fdb49b7
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: 0 {
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    name=android_metadata
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    tbl_name=android_metadata
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    rootpage=3
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: 1 {
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    name=users
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    tbl_name=users
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    rootpage=4
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE users(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username text)
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.273 I/System.out: 2 {
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out:    type=table
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out:    name=peserta
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out:    tbl_name=peserta
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out:    rootpage=5
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out:    sql=CREATE TABLE peserta(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,nama TEXT(100),jenis_kelamin TEXT(1),tempat_lahir TEXT(20),tgl_lahir TEXT(12),alamat TEXT(30),agama TEXT(30),id_ortu INTEGER,FOREIGN KEY (id_ortu) REFERENCES users(_id))
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out: }
12-29 10:01:37.274 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- Note that there is no need for DatabasePesertahelper as DatabaseUserHelper provides access to both tables.